# Can we migrate MKS 2009 to TFS 2010? If yes how and what tools are available?

Tags: .net, migration, mks, mks-integrity

I have got a task to migrate MKS Integrity to Team Foundation Server 2010 for some client. I am new to both of them.

I am familiar with SVN and clearcase and have used them for 2.5 years each. I liked SVN more than Clearcase ( just my opinion)

Now coming back to my task, I want to know if there are any tools to convert from MKS Integrity to TFS 2010? 
If yes, please guide me regarding how good the tools are if anyone has experiences regarding it.
If no, what should my strategy be to go ahead with the project?


NOTE : I am open to both free tools as well as commercial tools.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [TFS Integration Tookit / TFS Integration Platform.](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/02/tfs-integration-platform-or-tools-or-both.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: TFS Integration Toolkit and Platform are the primary way to migrate to TFS. If no adapter currently exists, you'll have to write them yourself.